Connect redis nodejs with Elasticache aws connect fail
I had a problem connecting to aws elasticache, I found some solutions but couldn't solve the problem. Hope anyone can help.
const redis = createClient({
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
    tls: true,
    connectTimeout: 30000,
  },
});




error logs
Redis Client Error Error: connect ETIMEDOUT


Is this code running in the same VPC as the ElastiCache server? Or is it running on your local computer or something? What are the security group rules of the ElastiCache server?

this code is running local, security group open port 6379(any where ipv4) , all traffic(any where ipv4) (inbound)

The ETIMEDOUT error typically occurs when the connection to the AWS ElastiCache (Redis) cluster cannot be established within the specified timeout. Check the connectivity, security groups, make sure the host name is correct.
Simple debug step: try to connect with cli command from the same security group, networking, and see wether you can connect or no.


"this code is running local"

ElastiCache servers don't get public IP addresses. If you do a DNS lookup of that hostname you are trying to connect to, you will see it is a private IP address that will only work within your VPC.

How can I choose to use a redis cache service?

Please clarify your question. I don't understand what your comment is asking.

The ElastiCache service is designed to be accessed exclusively from within AWS.
If you want to access it from your local machine, the easiest and the cheapest way is to you use Jumpbox/Bastion instance and AWS SSM Start-Session with port forwarding (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-remote-port-forwarding).
First install the Session Manager plugin for AWS CLI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html)
Login via CLI to AWS and run:
aws ssm start-session \
    --target jumpbox-instance-id \
    --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
    --parameters '{"host":["redis-host.abcdef.0001.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com"],"portNumber":["6379"], "localPortNumber":["6379"]}'

Then you can access your redis on localhost:6379. Make sure to test first with tls disabled.
